# C# to ruby checksum conversion

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a checksum that I need to add to a ruby string in hex.  I have been unable to convert the checksum successfully.  I am relatively new to ruby, so I'm not sure if I'm missing something.  Here is what I am doing:

```
  def get_checksum message
    # get the checksum
    cnt = 0
    lrc = 0
    while (cnt < message.length - 1)
      lrc = lrc ^ message[cnt].to_i
      cnt += 1
    end

    # return as hex
    lrc.to_s.each_byte.map { |b| b.to_s(16) + " " }.join
  end
```

I have some c# reference code as well, but have never used C# being a long time mac C/C++/Obj-C coder.  Here is the C# code I am trying to convert:

```
// calculate LRC
private string GetChecksum(string inputstring)
{
    int checksum = 0;
    foreach (char c in inputstring)
    {
        checksum ^= Convert.ToByte(c);
    }
    return checksum.ToString("X2");
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.to_i` will return `0` when called on a character.

```
def get_checksum message
   # get the checksum
   lrc = 0
   message.each_byte do |b|
      lrc = lrc ^ b
   end
   # return as hex
   lrc.to_s(16)
end
```